# how to generate dynamic page with Catch-all Segments in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am want to generate urls as:

```
/gallery/

/gallery/a

/gallery/b

/gallery/c
```

so i am using below code in file name: pages/gallery/[slug].js

```
const Gallery = ({ CurrentPage }) => {

    return (
        <>
        <h3>Galley Pages</h3>
        <p>Current page is: {CurrentPage}</p>
        </>
    )}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
 
    return {
        paths: [
            { params: { slug: "a" } },
            { params: { slug: "b" } },
            { params: { slug: "c" } }
        ],
        fallback: false
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

    const slug = params.slug;

    return {
        props: { CurrentPage: slug },
        revalidate: 1,
    }
}

export default Gallery
```

But its generate only:

```
/gallery/a

/gallery/b

/gallery/c
```

I have done some changes as:

perms as: {} as per https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments

But its start showing error that `slog` must be passed. i also tested by rename file as: [[...slug]].js but still not working.

I have uploaded full code at: https://github.com/nomadicshiv/Strapi-Next.js-Vercel-Pagination-Example

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `index.js` under the same `pages/gallery/...` as follows:

```
...
pages
   |__ gallery
       |__ [slug].js
       |__ index.js
   |__ ...
...
```

Using the **Optional Catch-all Segments** `[[...slug]].js` must work when you adjust `getStaticPaths` to render its paths properly by including the empty slug list as follows:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
 
    return {
        paths: [
            { params: { slug: [] } },
            { params: { slug: ["a"] } },
            { params: { slug: ["b"] } },
            { params: { slug: ["c"] } },
        ],
    }
}
```